# Implementing Design pattern and Spring MVC

Tags: java

How to use singleton design pattern with factory design pattern?How to many ways we can make communication between controller and jsp in spring MVC?

Answer (score 0):

You can use singleton along side the factory method , by applying the singleton pattern inside each method implemented in the factory pattern interface

(singleton inside methods(A class where only a single instance can exist) / factory implantation is in the interface of services, Creates an instance of many derived classes(methods))

```
interface ImageReader {
DecodedImage getDecodeImage();
}

class DecodedImage {
private String image;
public DecodedImage(String image) {this.image = image;}
@Override
public String toString() {return image + ": is decoded";}
}

class GifReader implements ImageReader {
private DecodedImage decodedImage;
public GifReader(String image) {
    this.decodedImage = new DecodedImage(image);}

@Override
public DecodedImage getDecodeImage() {return decodedImage;}
}
//this is a method implementing singleton inside a factory pattern
public class Singleton implements ImageReader {
private Singleton() {}
private static class SingletonHolder {private static final Singleton INSTANCE = new 
Singleton();}
public static Singleton getInstance() {return SingletonHolder.INSTANCE;}
}


public class FactoryMethodDemo {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    DecodedImage decodedImage;
    ImageReader reader = null;
    String image = args[0];
    String format = image.substring(image.indexOf('.') + 1, (image.length()));
    if (format.equals("gif")) {
        reader = new GifReader(image);
    }
    if (format.equals("singleton")) {
        reader = new Singleton();
    }

    assert reader == decodedImage;
    decodedImage = reader.getDecodeImage();
    System.out.println(decodedImage);
}
}
```

this site got more examples as well https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns